# How to test a file with IF and a variable from another file with PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html

I want to be able to enter something in a `<form>`, then in another php file check to see if the thing I put down exists.
Lets say I put in the text box `"Jilly"`
I want it to detect `"Jilly.txt"`
This is my code
File#1.php:

```
<form action="File#2.php" method="post">
<input name="user" type="text">
<input type="submit" value="Go">
```

File #2:

```
<?php
$user = $_POST["user"]
if (bool file_exists ( string $user )) {
    echo . $user . " filename exists."
}
else {
    echo . $user . " filename doesn't exist."
}
?>
```

So what am I doing wrong? When I click the "Go" input, it shows file#2 a blank file, so it there is something wrong with file#2's PHP code.

Comment: Well the `#` in your URIs is the first thing to fix. That's going to confuse URLs because `#` denotes the start of the hash, which is not sent to the server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The file names actually don't have a #, it's actually "Login.php" and "PLogin.php"

Comment: Why do you write `bool`, `string`? What's this for?

Comment: "File #1"="Login.php" and "File #2"="PLogin.php"

Comment: Bool and String is to locate the file I put in the Form text box

Comment: @u_mulder it's most likely misunderstood documentation.

Comment: There's a simple example of `file_exists` on php man page. Please RTFM carefully.

Comment: If the file you 're searching for exists in the same directory as your file #2, then your script should find the file. Only, if you type the full filename in your text box.

The bool and string stuff is superfluous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to php.

You're clearly reading documentation. Good job! Just understand that datatypes are information solely for the reader of the documentation and are not written out in the actual script.

Therefore change,

```
if (bool file_exists ( string $user )) {

to

if (file_exists ( $user . "txt" )) {
```

you probably did this because

```
bool file_exists ( string $filename )
```

is the way the function is written in the documentation. However, the first line is always just a very short reference, explaining all the datatypes. To see actual syntax, scroll down to examples. (Assuming you're reading on php.net)

Bool is the 'return type' - writing that down doesn't have any meaning and thus leads to an error. I also concatenated ".txt" so it checks for the file Jilly.txt rather than the file Jilly.

Your echos alsso aren't quite right. Write it like this:

```
echo $user . " filename exists.";
```

So remove the dot immediatly after the echo. The dot "concatenates" two strings, so it needs to have one string to the left and one to the right. A semicolon is also important.

And at last, change the file name so it doesn't contain a # anymore.

Comment: P.S. `bool file_exists()` could also be a misspelled value cast (which is useless in this case, since it would turn a boolean into a boolean). The correct syntax would be: `(bool) file_exists()`.

Comment: True, but I didn't mention it because of the inherit uselessness. ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors. The first one is, that a hash `#` is not allowed as part of a directory or file name in an URL. As written in the comments, the part after a hash is used as in-page anchor, to jump to a specific section.

For the next point refer to the answer of @KjeldSchmidt.